# An getting this error when i run my project: java.sql.SQLException: Locale not recognized

Tags: java, jdbc, locale

Help me to solve this error for project am developing

```
WARN [main] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(233) | SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
    ERROR [main] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(234) | Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Locale not recognized)
    WARN [main] SettingsFactory.buildSettings(147) | Could not obtain connection to query metadata
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Locale not recognized)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:454)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:396)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunWar.execute(Jetty6RunWar.java:67)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Locale not recognized
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.setSessionFields(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:965)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.<init>(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:185)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:352)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 77 more
    DEBUG [main] StartupListener.contextInitialized(43) | Initializing context...
    DEBUG [main] StartupListener.contextInitialized(88) | Remember Me Enabled? true
    DEBUG [main] StartupListener.contextInitialized(90) | Password Encoder: ShaPasswordEncoder
    DEBUG [main] StartupListener.contextInitialized(92) | Populating drop-downs...
    WARN [main] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(233) | SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
    ERROR [main] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(234) | Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Locale not recognized)
    WARN [main] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(233) | SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
    ERROR [main] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(234) | Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Locale not recognized)
    2012-03-13 16:24:16.609:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@d210ab{/,E:\Private\Projects\recon\recon\target\recon-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war}
    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy105.getAllRoles(Unknown Source)
        at com.tra.atm.recon.webapp.listener.StartupListener.setupContext(StartupListener.java:108)
        at com.tra.atm.recon.webapp.listener.StartupListener.contextInitialized(StartupListener.java:95)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:454)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:396)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunWar.execute(Jetty6RunWar.java:67)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    2012-03-13 16:24:16.611:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection:
    java.sql.SQLException: Locale not recognized
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.setSessionFields(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:965)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.<init>(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:185)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:352)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy105.getAllRoles(Unknown Source)
        at com.tra.atm.recon.webapp.listener.StartupListener.setupContext(StartupListener.java:108)
        at com.tra.atm.recon.webapp.listener.StartupListener.contextInitialized(StartupListener.java:95)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:454)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:396)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunWar.execute(Jetty6RunWar.java:67)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Answer (score 11):

> ```
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Locale not recognized
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
> ```

Your operating system platform default locale is apparently not supported by the Oracle JDBC driver. Change your operating system platform default locale to something more common. You can also do it on a per JVM runtime basis by adding the following VM arguments:

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
```

This sets the JVM default locale to `en_US` (English / United States).

You can check as follows which default locale exactly is currently been used by your operating system platform:

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 8):

As just suggested you will see this problem if

1. You pass different locale to your application
2. In the code, jdbc tries to establish connection with this locale
3. But the locale is not supported by the DBMS

So, you can do the following

1. Take backup of current locale

   `Locale backup = Locale.getDefault();`
2. Set locale before acquiring connection

   `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);`
3. Acquire connection
4. Set the backup locale

Hope this helps.

-Kiran

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by just changing my location and country in control panel.
i changed it to United State and English.
As an iranian we are in sanction of software too. this is US honesty!

Comment: they banned us from downloading open source project  despite the philosophy of open world

Comment: You saved my day! I wonder why all other solutions don't work for me on mac and surprisingly the answer was on the system preferences!

Answer (score 1):

This problem must be solved if you are using products of jetBrains company.

You will get a error like "Connection to @[your oracle database host] failed. [99999][17176] locale not recognized!"(Chinese: "无法识别区域设置")
when trying to connect your oracle database by DataGrip.

The solution is to solve the locale problem of JDBC. If you use Unix, try to add this code into your bash profile.

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.language=zh -Duser.region=zh_CN -Duser.country=zh_CN"
```

**Of course, replace above keywords which are about locale by yours.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be caused by a framework/jdbc version mismatch. I solved the same problem by upgrading the jdbc driver. My set up was:

```
Spring Boot  2.7.3

MyBatis 2.3.0

OJDBC6 11.2.0.4
```

Upgraded to OJDBC8 and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably, you have locale not supported by Oracle JDBC.